# MySQL group by with 2 columns when values are interchanged in columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

See this table. It contains a chat log with incoming and outgoing messages

```
    id | to_number    | from_number  |message         | direction| type   |  generated_time
     1 | +15005550004 | +16232950692 |Hai             | OUTGOING |        | 2019-07-12 15:13:00
     2 | +16232950692 | +15005550004 |Hello           | INCOMING | REVIEW | 2019-07-13 18:13:00
     3 | +15005550004 | +16232950692 |How are you ?   | OUTGOING |        | 2019-07-13 21:15:00
     4 | +15005550001 | +16232950692 |Good morning    | OUTGOING |        | 2019-07-12 12:13:00
     5 | +16232950692 | +15005550001 |Have a nice day | INCOMING | REVIEW | 2019-07-12 12:17:00
     6 | +15005550007 | +16232950692 |Hey John        | OUTGOING |        | 2019-07-12 14:13:00
```

Now i want to get the last generated message in each threads in which we got an incoming message with type REVIEW.
See the desired output

```
    to_number    | from_number  |message         | direction| type   | generated_time
    +15005550004 | +16232950692 |How are you ?   | OUTGOING |        | 2019-07-13 21:15:00
    +16232950692 | +15005550001 |Have a nice day | INCOMING | REVIEW | 2019-07-12 12:17:00
```

I tried a query

```
    select *
    from (select b.*
          from (select *
                from message m
                where m.id in (select min(msg.id)
                        from message msg
                        where msg.direction = 'INCOMING'
                        group by msg.from_number, msg.to_number)
                  and m.type = 'REVIEW') a
                 left join (select * from message m) b 
                  on ((a.from_number = b.to_number and a.to_number = b.from_number) or
                      (a.from_number = b.from_number and a.to_number = b.to_number))
          order by b.generated_time desc
    ) c group by from_number,to_number order by generated_time desc;
```

But it is not grouping the messages properly.
Can anybody help me to find a solution for this ?

Comment: Pls elaborate what exactly `it is not grouping the messages properly` means through providing actual results. Also, you left the type field and its description out of the question.

Comment: first I'll suggest using column names instead of * when using group by, it helps you identify which columns you need to use aggregate functions on. second, you need to add complete details here, you cannot leave out one column and expect others to help you fix it.

Comment: as Shadow mentioned, you are using `type` column in query, but you have not included into your sample data.

Comment: Sorry, i have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to determine the "thread" for each row is [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) the [`LEAST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) of the two numbers with the [`GREATEST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) of the same two numbers.

We can then `GROUP BY` on the "thread", to get the latest `generated_time`. In `HAVING` clause, we filter out only those "thread", which has atleast one `'INCOMING'` message with `'REVIEW'` type.

**[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/agNSG2Xy4tUTfM4UNRj1tf/0)**

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM   message AS m1
       JOIN (SELECT Concat(Least(m.from_number, m.to_number), '|',
                                                      Greatest(m.from_number,
                                                      m.to_number))
                                              AS
                    thread,
                    Max(m.generated_time)
                                              AS max_generated_time
             FROM   message AS m
             GROUP  BY thread
             HAVING Sum(m.direction = 'INCOMING'
                        AND m.type = 'REVIEW')) AS dt
         ON dt.thread = Concat(Least(m1.from_number, m1.to_number), '|',
                                         Greatest(m1.from_number, m1.to_number))
            AND dt.max_generated_time = m1.generated_time;
```

**Result**

```
| id  | to_number    | from_number  | message         | direction | type   | generated_time      |
| --- | ------------ | ------------ | --------------- | --------- | ------ | ------------------- |
| 3   | +15005550004 | +16232950692 | How are you ?   | OUTGOING  |        | 2019-07-13 21:15:00 |
| 5   | +16232950692 | +15005550001 | Have a nice day | INCOMING  | REVIEW | 2019-07-12 12:17:00 |
```

---

**Sidenote:**

1. Above approach (and your current schema design) is not able to use indexes, and hence it will not be *performant*.
2. I would rather redesign the schema by creating two additional Master tables. One Master table would be storing the phone numbers: `phone_id`, and `number`
3. Another Master table would be storing the "Thread", which will contain the `phone_id` values and `thread_id`. You can then use this `thread_id` in your `message` table, instead of storing the phone numbers.