# MYSQL query for selection and Grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following MySQL table

```
---------------------------------
| ID_One | ID_two  | Get_val    |
---------------------------------
|   44   | 50      | 1          |
---------------------------------
|   20   | 32      | 1          |
---------------------------------
|   30   | 14      | 1          |
---------------------------------
|   50   | 44      | 2          |
---------------------------------
```

I want to get the result as follows.

```
---------------------------------
| ID_One | ID_two  | **SUM_val**|
---------------------------------
|   44   | 50      | 3          |
---------------------------------
|   50   | 44      | 3          |
---------------------------------
```

Can some one assist in witting the above query ?
This what I am running currently.

```
select ID_One,ID_Two, SUM(Get_val) 
from getList 
where ID_one='44' OR ID_two='44' 
group by ID_one, ID_two;
```

Comment: on what condition you need to group?

Comment: From the point it is ID_one and two

Comment: @Tom, what you have tried for the result.

Comment: I have the user_id 44 and needs to grab the results as mentioned in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you basically need `SUM()` of all the `Get_val` values where either `ID_One` or `ID_Two` is **44**. Afterwards, you want to display all the unique combinations of `ID_One` and `ID_Two` with the "overall sum".

We can get the "overall sum" in a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-tables.html); and then `CROSS JOIN` it back to the Main table, to get the required rows:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT t.ID_One, t.ID_Two, dt.tot_sum 
FROM getList AS t 
CROSS JOIN 
(
  SELECT SUM(Get_val) AS tot_sum 
  FROM getList 
  WHERE ID_One = '44' OR ID_Two = '44'
) AS dt 
WHERE t.ID_One = '44' OR t.ID_Two = '44'
```

**Result**

```
| ID_One | ID_Two | tot_sum |
| ------ | ------ | ------- |
| 44     | 50     | 3       |
| 50     | 44     | 3       |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4o1bYWg3A9ZLRXY3zr9dsp/0)

Comment: sounds good and close to the result,  fiddle updated and can track disparity

Comment: @Tom what is the disparity ? What should be your expected result as per the updated fiddle.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4o1bYWg3A9ZLRXY3zr9dsp/1 can see the total sum of all rather than gettng 3 and 2 corresponding

Comment: Ok now your problem makes sense..that is why problem statement needs to have more sample data, for clarity..anyways check this answer of me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57033530/mysql-group-by-with-2-columns-when-values-are-interchanged-in-columns/57033949#57033949

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment as you have 44 as user_id filter then.
This may help you:

```
SELECT ID_One,ID_two, (SELECT SUM(Get_val) FROM tplink WHERE tplink.ID_One = 44 OR tplink.ID_two = 44) as sum FROM `tplink` WHERE ID_One=44 OR ID_two = 44
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry it is not valid one

Comment: Yes, but for now this is what may give him clue until he will not provide current query which he is using.

Answer (score 1):

Could be using some subquery for manage alternated  values  matching

```
select  id_one, id_two, sum(get_val)
from (

    select  m1.ID_One, m1.ID_two, m1.getval
    from my_table m1 
    inner join  ( 
        select one, two
        from (
            select id_one one, id_two two
            from  my_table  
            union all 
            select two, id_one
            from  my_table a 
        ) t 
        group by one, two
        having count(*) > 1 
        ) t1  on t1.one = m1.id_one and t1.two = m1.id_two

    union all 

    select  m1.ID_One, m1.ID_two, m1.getval
    from my_table m1 
    inner join  ( 
        select one, two
        from (
            select id_one one, id_two two
            from  my_table  
            union all 
            select two, id_one
            from  my_table a 
        ) t 
        group by one, two
        having count(*) > 1 
        ) t1  on t1.two = m1.id_one and t1.one = m1.id_two
)  t2 
group by id_one, id_two
```

Comment: :-(|) UQL (Unstructured Query Language) from Stackoverflow, personally thanks for your answer @scaisEdge, I will try to resolve it myself

Comment: @Tom   ... work  ??   .. not work ??? this is the question  ...  you  get the expected  result  ??? ... .

Comment: ..  this don't change my answer ...  and overall my comment

Comment: Its not working either, but it have huge resource consumption right ?